# Handle C assertions from python

Tags: python, exception, wrapper, assert

I used the following python code to compress a dicom file using GDCM:

```
    import gdcm

    reader = gdcm.PixmapReader()
    reader.SetFileName(str(source))
    if not reader.Read():
        raise BaseException("Could not read (pixmap) %s" % source)
    image = reader.GetPixmap()
    change = gdcm.ImageChangeTransferSyntax()
    change.SetForce(False)
    change.SetCompressIconImage(False)
    transfer_syntax = gdcm.TransferSyntax(gdcm.TransferSyntax.JPEG2000Lossless)
    change.SetTransferSyntax(transfer_syntax)
    change.SetInput(image)
    if not change.Change():
        raise BaseException("Could not change the Transfer Syntax: ")
    ....
```

In the line `change.Change()`, there's an assertion in GDCM source which may faile:

```
Assertion `((fragment_size + 1)/2 ) * 2 == ((image_height * image_width * numcomps * (bitsallocated/8) + 1)/ 2 )* 2' failed.
```

Unfortunately python process would be killed in the case of assertion failure at GDCM. Is there a way to handle such assertions (without having checked the conditions at python before calling `change.Change()`)?

Comment: Did you try with an exception handler: something like: `try: change.Change(); except Assertion: ...`

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE: C assertions don't work that way.

Comment: This `assert` is triggered for a programmer error, can you reproduce the issue with a publicly available DICOM dataset ?

Comment: @malat: The assertion fail for about less than 0.5% of my DICOMs which are sent by real modalities such as Siemens CT-scan and .... May be the file is damaged or was uncorrected at first, but I want to ignore it instead of my process to be closed totally.

Comment: @mtoloo This is called a bug. Run your python script using `$ gdb python my_gdcm.py`, wait until the `assert` is triggered, do a `bt`, find the filename in the tracestack and send me a copy of the problematic file. The logic looks correct I need a sample to understand what's wrong.

Comment: @malat: I have a problematic Dicom file created by SIEMENS which does not satisfies the assertion in GDCM `/MediaStorageAndFileFormat/gdcmJPEG2000Codec.cxx` line 937 since `((fragment_size + 1)/2 ) * 2` = 349142 is not equal with `((image_height * image_width * numcomps * (bitsallocated/8) + 1)/ 2 )* 2 )`=524288. 
`fragment_size` = 349141,
`image_height` & `image_width` = 512,
`sample_pixel` = 1,
`bitsallocated` = 16,
How can I send you this file?

Comment: http://gdcm.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/General_questions#Where_are_the_GDCM_mailing_lists_.3F

Comment: @malat: Viewing that Dicom with a viewer, I noticed that the problem is in the file self since the picture is truncated! So it's not a bug in gdcm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reluctantly I checked the Dicom integrity using `pydicom` before compressing Dicom:

```
def check_dicom(dicom_file):
    p = dicom.read_file(dicom_file)
    assert p.SamplesPerPixel in (1, 3)
    if p.BitsAllocated % 8 != 0:
        return False

    # assert( ((fragment_size + 1)/2 ) * 2 == ((image_height * image_width * numcomps * (bitsallocated/8) + 1)/ 2 )* 2 );
    left = ((len(p.PixelData) + 1)/2 ) * 2
    right = ((p.Rows * p.Columns * p.SamplesPerPixel * (p.BitsAllocated/8) + 1)/ 2 )* 2
    if left != right:
        raise BaseException("DICOM attributes are in conflict with pixel data size")
    return True
```

Answer (score 1):

A way to handle this is to start a child process to call the C library, then raise an exception if the child process dies because of a C assert statement.